# nmcli, how to get "connection.id" or "general.name" of device

Tags: networking, scripts, network-manager, nmcli

I am writing a script on 16.04; to show connection identification, especially for VPN connections, by listing ***active*** connections with

`ip -o link sh up | awk 'BEGIN{FS=": "} $2!="lo" {print $2}'`

and getting:

```
enp0s25  
ppp0
```

Now I want to get/return the Connection NAME, the same as from:

```
#: nmcli  con sh --active
NAME             UUID                                  TYPE            DEVICE  
VPN-pptp-01      22222222-2222-f48f-99d0-817335722def  vpn             enp0s25 
enp0s25          11111111-1111-43c9-9577-112ae6f11abc  802-3-ethernet  enp0s25
```

using the previously return active device ID, especially for ppp0 *(from above)*

How can this be done using *nmcli* or perhaps D-Bus?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following command:

```
nmcli -t -f NAME c show --active
```

Comment: `nmcli -t -f NAME c s -a` returns the connection name with no way to associate the link device, in this case "ppp0" and thus return the IP address.    

Further, `nmcli -t -f NAME,DEVICE c s -a` does not return ppp0, but instead the ethernet device interface.  

I need to be able to return for the link:  
    + the IP address,
    + gateway IP address,
    + connection name  
 for the link, in this case ppp0

Comment: Looks like I might have to use 'C' or Python code to solve this.  
Does anyone have any light to shine on this problem, i.e. For all **Active Links**, i.e link state up, I need to print out the following:  
* link device,     e.g. "ppp0", "enp0s25"  
* Connection Name, e.g. "VPN-pptp-01", "Wired connection 1"  
* Connection Type, e.g. "vpn", "ethernet"  
* IP Address  
* Gateway IP Address

Comment: It is weird that your actual VPN device did not show up as tun0 or other device with nmcli. In my box, at least 3 entries: eth0, my-VPN, and tun0.